# Bluemix failed to deploy and can't get logs

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a node.js app, build fine, but it fails to deploy with this error:

> FAILED
>   Error restarting application: StagingError

It says I should run logs --recent, it connects, but I get an error with that:

> FAILED
>   Error dialing trafficcontroller server: Get https://doppler.w3ibm.bluemix.net:4443/apps/3603f2cc-d0b6-41c7-91e8-62d2636b71dc/recentlogs: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
>   Please ask your Cloud Foundry Operator to check the platform configuration (trafficcontroller endpoint is wss://doppler.w3ibm.bluemix.net:4443).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a temporary issue with the loggregator which is causing problems getting the logs. Log in again using `cf login` and try the `cf logs appname --recent` command again.

Note: Issues with IBM internal Bluemix deployments shouldn't be asked on StackOverflow.